# addSubview only working in viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, addsubview

I'm working on an app which must display a YouTube video when a button is pressed.

I'm using code found elsewhere on the site which appears to function fine under most circumstances, however in my case it is not.

```
- (void)displayVideo{

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(5,55, 200,310);
    NSLog(@"Trying to display video with ID: %@", videoID);
    NSString *embedHTML =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                          <html><head>\
                          <style type=\"text/css\">\
                          body {\
                          background-color: transparent;\
                          color: white;\
                          }\
                          </style>\
                          </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
                          <iframe height=\"200\" width=\"310\"      src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@\"></iframe>\
                          </body></html>", videoID];
    UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    videoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [videoView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:videoView];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay]; }
```

The method is run when the button is pressed. The NSLog goes through fine, so I know the code is being run - the view appears to refuse to update though.

On a whim, I tried putting the code in the ViewController's viewDidLoad method and surprisingly, it worked fine.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this may be?

Comment: Are you missing some tiny detail when calling displayVideo? Can you post displayVideo declaration in the .h file? and also the call, as well as from where you are calling it?

Comment: I checked your code and it's working for me. I think it is also working for you, just change the background color of your view. (Means set self.view 's background color to green)

Comment: I think you need to wait for sometime to see the effect may be your uiwebview is taking time to load, since you were trying on `ViewDidAppear` which is the last state when a viewcontroller loads..

Comment: The two obvious questions have you confirmed with the debugger that (a) displayVideo is being executed, and (b) videoID has been set at the time it is called?

Comment: Don't add `UIWebView` on button click. Add it in `viewDidLoad:` method  and on button Action just load html string.

Comment: how you are calling this method? can you show that code?

Comment: I have copied your code in one of my button click event. Its working fine .

Comment: is your button is from xib or created programmatically?

Comment: Well in Autolayout you need to set some properties of Sub View that you are adding before adding it to subview like translateAutoresizepropertytoconstraint some thing like that, make sure this is not the issue,

Comment: Try with commenting this line - [self.view setNeedsDisplay];

Comment: @RegularExpression I've 100% confirmed that displayVideo executes and videoID has been set at the time it's called.

Comment: @TheTiger I'll try that now.

Comment: @Dilip I don't think the issue is in regards to the method being called, though I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the subview in viewDidLoad, keep them hidden till the button is pressed and then set the value of the hidden property to NO when the button is pressed.

That said I can't see a reason why a view wont be added to the hierarchy outside the viewDidLoad. Since this is a webView I think you could try adding it to the view hierarchy inside the delegate method named `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView`. Don't forget to set the delegate properly.